# VLOOKUP + MATCH and MAX value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi i am trying to do a VLOOKUP with match and i succesfully did.
My formula looks like this:

```
VLOOKUP(A5;D:I;MATCH(B5;$A$1:$K$9;0);FALSE)
```

I know that VLOOKUP selects the first match, however i need it to pick the highest value. So my formula at the moment gives me value "100"(E5), when i need it to select value "300"(E6).

```
A    B              C           D       E      F       G    H       I

1    Company    Profession              1      2     3      4       5
2    A              2           A             534          531  
3    B              2           B      123          412     
4    C              1           C             213           
5    D              1           D      100          112     
6    D              1           D      300          231 
7    D              1           D      200          752     
8    E              3           E             123    55    431
9    F              4           F                                  112
```

Can you help me with this? I am absolutely lost.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following SUMPRODUCT() Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($E$2:$I$9)*(A5=$D$2:$D$9)*(B5=$E$1:$I$1)))
```

Or the following AGGREGATE() formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(14;6;($E$2:$I$9)/((A5=$D$2:$D$9)*(B5=$E$1:$I$1)),1)
```